# JMS Serializer Overriding Groups in FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I read [this article](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies) about overriding groups of child properties:

```
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;

$context = SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array(
    'Default', // Serialize John's name
    'manager_group', // Serialize John's manager
    'friends_group', // Serialize John's friends

    'manager' => array( // Override the groups for the manager of John
        'Default', // Serialize John manager's name
        'friends_group', // Serialize John manager's friends. If you do not override the groups for the friends, it will default to Default.
    ),

    'friends' => array( // Override the groups for the friends of John
        'manager_group' // Serialize John friends' managers.

        'manager' => array( // Override the groups for the John friends' manager
            'Default', // This would be the default if you did not override the groups of the manager property.
        ),
    ),
));
$serializer->serialize($john, 'json', $context);
```

In FOSRestBundle I am using the `@View` annotation with the `serializerGroups` property:

```
/**
 * @Rest\Get("/api/users/{id}", name="api_get_user")
 * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"Default", "detail", "friends":{"Default"})
 */
public function getAction(Request $request, User $user = null)
{
    return $user;
}
```

How can I override child properties using that annotation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If someone finds a better and shorter way **with annotations** I can award the bounty (since I can't get it back).

The only way to override nested properties' groups is to get the **serializer context** from the view and set the groups from there. Here it is:

```
/**
 * @Rest\Get("/api/users/profile", name="api_get_profile")
 */
public function profileAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    // sets different groups for nested properties
    $view = $this->view($user);
    $view->getContext()->setGroups(array(
        'Default',
        'user_detail',
        'user_profile',
        'friends' => array(
            'Default',
        )
    ));

    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

This way my `profileAction` will return an user with all the `user_detail` and `user_profile` groups, but the items in the `friends` property, which contains an array of User, will just contain the properties defined in the `Default` group.

This is the result:

```
{
    "id": 532,
    "username": "someuser",
    "email": "someuser@example.com",
    "enabled": true,
    "last_login": "2017-11-10T09:45:51+01:00",
    "notification_id": "ABC",
    "avatar_id": 3,
    "friends": [
        {
            "id": 530,
            "username": "anotheruser",
            "avatar_id": 5
        },
        {
            "id": 554,
            "username": "johndoe",
            "avatar_id": 7
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We are using Symfony 3.4 with FOSRestBundle 2.3.1 and nested properites are working in annotations for us:

```
class FooController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     * @View(serializerGroups={"Default", "api:foo:details", "subfoos"={"Default", "api:foo:summary"}})
     */
    public function fooAction(Foo $foo){
        return $foo;
    }
}
```

`$foo->subfoos` field is serialized with groups `"Default", "api:foo:summary"`.